# Message Format thread safety

Tags: java

HI could anyone please tell me the answers to following.
--Is java.text.MessageFormat class thread safe??(y/n)
--is it true that out of many format methods in java.text.MessageFormat only 1 is thread safe since it creates a local instance of MessageFormat every time.??(y/n)

can anyone provide an explannation also to above two questions?
can anyone provide a code which shows  java.text.MessageFormat  is not threadsafe?

Comment: If this is indeed homework, then tutor apparently want you to be able to find and understand javadocs :) Work on that. Javadocs are #1 source for answers you ever need on questions about some class.

Answer (score 5):

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> **Synchronization**
>
> Message formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create
>   separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access
>   a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Comment: GMTA, I posted *Exactly* the same answer :D I deleted it. +1.